# How to use AJAX url in localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to give url? in localhost Wordpress... this code not working in     localhost but url working in server. this code throw the error..it is cannot reach the url

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajaxpu.php",     
    type: "POST",//post not working
    data: {'offset': 6, 'cat': 3, 'next':'next'},
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        jQuery('.response'+cat).html(result);
        jQuery('.load-next1 .loader').hide();
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery(".publications-section").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    },
});
```

Comment: Does the return value from `get_template_directory_uri` start with a `/` character? If not, the same url path may be treated differently depending what file structure it is being read from.

Comment: You could try opening up the network tab of your dev-tools. Look for `ajaxpu.php` and hover over it to see the full path of the url, make sure it is what you expect.

Comment: Can you please show the error you're getting? Is it a JS error or a PHP error? What is the HTTP code you're receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code.

```
jQuery.ajax
        ({
        url: get_template_directory_uri() . "/ajaxpu.php",     
        type: "POST",//post not working
         data: {'offset': 6, 'cat': 3, 'next':'next'},
         cache: false,
        success: function(result){
        jQuery('.response'+cat).html(result);
          jQuery('.load-next1 .loader').hide();
         jQuery('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: jQuery(".publications-section").offset().top
           }, 1000);
         },
          });
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply...but this code is not working

Comment: did you declare the get_template_directory_uri() function?